# permission denied when opening a file when user has dropped root privileges

Tags: c, linux

The situation below is that I have a file that is owned by root but has read privileges by anyone in the adm group. I have a user, haen with uid 1000, which is part of adm group. I can read it from command line:

> ```
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ id
> uid=1000(haen) gid=1000(haen) groups=1000(haen),4(adm),6(disk),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),100(users),120(lpadmin),121(sambashare),122(vboxusers),999(bumblebee)
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ ll file 
> -rw-r----- 1 root adm 13 okt 13 17:24 file
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ cat file 
> file content
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$
> ```

Further, I can open it as O_RDONLY in a c program test.c, if I run the compiled program as haen:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(const int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gid_t rgid, egid, sgid;
    uid_t ruid, euid, suid;
    int ret, test_fd;

    ret = getresgid(&rgid, &egid, &sgid);
    printf("1: getresgid() returned %d rgid: %d, egid: %d, sgid: %d\n",
           ret, rgid, egid, sgid);

    ret = getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
    printf("2: getresuid() returned %d ruid: %d, euid: %d, suid: %d\n",
           ret, ruid, euid, suid);

    test_fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
    printf("3: test_fd: %d\n", test_fd);
    close(test_fd);

    if(ruid == 0) {
        rgid = sgid = egid = 1000;
        ruid = euid = suid = 1000;

        ret = setresgid(rgid, egid, sgid);
        printf("4: setresgid() returned %d\n",ret);
        ret = getresgid(&rgid, &egid, &sgid);
        printf("5: getresgid() returned %d rgid: %d, egid: %d, sgid: %d\n",
               ret, rgid, egid, sgid);

        ret = setresuid(ruid, euid, suid);
        printf("6: setresuid() returned %d\n",ret);
        ret = getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
        printf("7: getresuid() returned %d ruid: %d, euid: %d, suid: %d\n",
               ret, ruid, euid, suid);

        test_fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
        printf("8: test_fd: %d\n", test_fd);
        close(test_fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ ./test 
> 1: getresgid() returned 0 rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
> 2: getresuid() returned 0 ruid: 1000, euid: 1000, suid: 1000
> 3: test_fd: 3
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$
> ```

BUT, and this is what puzzles me, if I run the program as root, and internally in the program drop my privileges to haen (inside the if-clause), the same as I have when running the program as haen, then I can no longer open "file" for reading, output:

> ```
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ sudo ./test
> 1: getresgid() returned 0 rgid: 0, egid: 0, sgid: 0
> 2: getresuid() returned 0 ruid: 0, euid: 0, suid: 0
> 3: test_fd: 3
> 4: setresgid() returned 0
> 5: getresgid() returned 0 rgid: 1000, egid: 1000, sgid: 1000
> 6: setresuid() returned 0
> 7: getresuid() returned 0 ruid: 1000, euid: 1000, suid: 1000
> 8: test_fd: -1
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$
> ```

Does anyone know why privileges dropped from root to a specific user, is not the same as having those user privileges from start ? I checked with strace, and the error code I get when trying to open is:

> ```
> 17:54:39.339041 open("file", O_RDONLY)  = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
> ```

Thus the value -1 for test_fd on the printout "8"

strace shows nothing else that explains this behavior, as far as I can see.

Environment:

> ```
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$ uname -a
> Linux haen-Precision-5510 4.4.0-97-generic 120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> haen@haen-Precision-5510:~/tmp$
> ```

The only explanation I can think of is that the linux kernel has a list of all gid's a user belongs to, and that this list is "dropped" when I do sudo and then back to my original user inside the c-program, but I don't know. As far as I understand the kernel does not read /etc/group but somehow it needs to know that a user belongs to a group when checking permissions.

Comment: Does this happen when you change the group id to 4 instead of 1000?

Comment: I've tried both egid/sgid set to 1000 and 4. It works when I set it to 4, which kind of makes sense. But rgid, egid and sgid is 1000 when I run the program as haen (user 1000) and then it works, so why not with the same rgid/egid/sgid when dropping from root to haen ? That is what bothers me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not handled the ancillary groups (`setgroups`).

When you `sudo`, you lose all of your group membership. Try the following:

```
$ sudo id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

So you run your program with the groups list containing just 0. You then explicitly set the real, effective and saved GIDs to 1000. This leaves the group list as containing only 0.

Since you are now not a member of the `adm` group, your file would not open.

Please remember that calling `setresgid` is not the same as logging in via the system. When that happens, it also checks which groups you are a member of and uses `setgroups` to set your process' permissions accordingly.